# Django form with a ModelChoiceField on a UUID do not show its content in cleaned_data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model:

```
class Code(models.Model):
    section = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    code_uid = models.UUIDField()    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.section
```

and a form:

```
class MyForm(Form):
    code_uid = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Code.objects.all(), to_field_name="code_uid")
```

But the following code after a POST of this form:

```
if my_form.is_valid():            
    print(my_form)
    print(my_form.cleaned_data)
    print(my_form.cleaned_data["code_uid"])
    print(type(my_form.cleaned_data["code_uid"]))
```

Prints:

for **my_form** a correctly displayed HTML:

```
<tr><th><label for="id_code_uid">Code uid:</label></th><td><select name="code_uid" required id="id_code_uid">
  <option value="">---------</option>

  <option value="e3112238-0768-1111-aaaa-4654ab799752">foo</option>

  <option value="e3112238-0768-1111-aaaa-4654ab799752">bar</option>
```

for **my_form.cleaned_data**:

```
{'code_uid': <Code: foo>}  <== should be the UUID
```

for **my_form.cleaned_data["code_uid"]**:

```
foo
```

for **type(my_form.cleaned_data["code_uid"])**:

```
<class 'creator.models.Code'>
```

How should I get my UUID value in the cleaned_values dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to accomplish:

- `to_field_name` just specifies what should be used as value in the form; it should be unique (okay, an uuid is practically unique...). But it serves no purpose here, since by default the django-autogenerated pk is used, which is guaranteed to be unique
- what `my_form.cleaned_data["code_uid"]` contains in any case is the instance of the `creator.models.Code` model you selected in the form. You can get `my_form.cleaned_data["code_uid"].code_uid` for the UUID and do with it what you wanted.

Comment: Exactly, .code_uid  I just found it a few seconds ago with a pdb hard search. Thanks